# Can I use the same optic fibre cable for single mode or multimode?

Tags: optical-cable

I have laid a 6 core FO i have already used in single mode, and I am now told the media converter has to be multimode. I have no information on the type of cable itself, so the question is:

Can a FO be compatible with both single and multi mode

Comment: Formally - no. Really - if the optic cable is multi (PC/UPC) and the length is short enough, then single may work (280m MM with DEM-302S - works). So you must test.

Comment: What if the cable is ment for single, can it work on multi mode. Distance is 50m

Comment: I doubt - MM needs core diameter 55 mkm at least whereas SM have 9 mkm only...

Comment: You may use additional MM-to-SM converter. Or buy SM media converter instead of existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know...

- Single-mode transceivers can use multi-mode fiber with some loss in distance; there are "mode conditioning" patch cords which improve the situation.
- Multi-mode transceivers **cannot** use single-mode fiber because most of the light will be unable to enter the fiber core in the first place. (As I understand it, it's like pointing a large torch at a pinhole.) It might work at very short distances only, due to massive loss in transmit power.

References:

- https://archive.nanog.org/meetings/nanog57/presentations/Monday/mon.tutorial.Steenbergen.Optical.39.pdf#page=15 (slide 15)
- http://www.fiber-optic-transceiver-module.com/will-single-mode-fiber-work-over-multimode-fiber-transceiver.html
- https://community.fs.com/blog/single-mode-cabling-cost-vs-multimode-cabling-cost.html (FAQ at bottom)